# Do I need to have an apple Developer ID to use HomeKit framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, homekit

Hi I'm trying to add a home to the database, but i get an error.

```
[self.homeManager addHomeWithName:@"Enfield" completionHandler:^(HMHome *home, NSError *error)
{
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to add home. \n%@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Home added Sucessfully \n%@", home);
    }
}];
```

I get an error:

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)" (connection to service named com.apple.homed.xpc) UserInfo=0x7f9e9b965290 {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.homed.xpc}

I looked in other posts and it looks like you have to have Developer ID, but that just doesn't make sense Apple allows to develop everything without an ID, but not the HomeKit. Can someone please shed a light on this.

EDIT:

GitHub link https://github.com/zlDev/HomeKitDemo

NinjaEDIT: Some code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To see if you got an error, don't test `error`. Instead, the test should be

```
if (home == nil) {
```

If there is an error, then `error` points to a description of the error; if there was not an error, `error` may be nil or may point to garbage.

---

OK, I dug a little deeper.

The error `connection to service named com.apple.homed.xpc` means that Xcode cannot connect to the HomeKit Accessory Simulator, which it would normally do through the Mach port named com.apple.homed.xpc. (The .xpc is the clue that this is for program-to-program commnunication. It's not a URL.)

The HomeKit documentation says that to start the HK Simulator, you need to add HomeKit to the list of your project's capabilities, and then use the menu command Xcode→Open Developer Tool→HomeKit Accessory Simulator. When I created a dummy iOS project and tried to add the HomeKit capability, Xcode at first refused because I had not yet agreed to Apple's latest terms of service.

Which answers your question. You cannot turn on the HomeKit capability without an Apple Developer ID.

What it doesn't answer is whether the developer ID has to be a paid developer ID. It might suffice to set up a free developer ID. That gives Apple a mechanism to get your agreement to Apple's terms of service, and might be all they need for now.

But even after I finally got the HomeKit capability turned on, the menu command was not available. Apparently you need to also go to developer.apple.com/downloads and download "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode 6.1", which includes the HomeKit Accessory Simulator". You will need an Apple Developer ID (of some level) to download the file.

Comment: It makes no difference. This actual code snippet is taken directly from WWDC conference, so it must be right.

Comment: So I see. That's pretty sloppy coding, though. The usual rule for any method that takes an `NSError**` parameter is as I described: the method will have some other way to signal failure, and you should only examine the error parameter if there is an error. -addHomeWithName:completionHandler: is documented that it sets `home` to nil in the callback if there is an error. It does also document that it sets `error` to nil on success, but that's unusual, and a bad habit to get into. Technically, I suppose this is an `NSError*` and not an `NSError**` parameter

Comment: Appreciate the detailed response. The free acc doesn't work it actually says that the acc must be enrolled in dev program for HomeKit to be enabled. Sorry can't +1 not enough reputation.

Comment: What if you enroll in the Safari developer program, which is free? Just a thought.

Comment: Might just work. I joined iOS program so now I can't tell. Maybe someone else can try this later and update us on with the results.

Comment: I done register with safari development but it did not help, i think i have to spent 99$.

Comment: after some recherche i now that the only way to use home kit framework without a payed licence is to use xcode 6 beta 2 or 3 but i can't find this 2 version